# Prove that $R$ as a ring is the direct sum of its homogeneous components.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $T$ be a simple left $R$-module. Assume that $_RR=\mathrm{Soc}(_RR）$. Prove that the $T$-homogeneous component of $_RR$ is a ring direct summand of $R$, and deduce that as a ring, $R$ is the direct sum of its homogeneous components.
I can get it from the Wedderburn-Artin theorem, but I have not learnt it now, can somebody give me a detail proof ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $_R R$ and $\mathrm{Soc}(_R R)$?

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva $_RR$ is a regular module of ring $R$ and the latter is the socle of $_RR$.

Comment: Usually this is used in the proof of the artin Wedderburn theorem, so I doubt it's a good idea to use it... It's simple enough to prove anyhow.

Comment: @ rschwieb Yes, I know this, but I haven't learnt it now

Answer (score 3):

The T homogeneous component is obviously a left ideal. It is easy to show it is a right ideal also. (Hint: if S is a simple left ideal, show Sr is an isomorphic left ideal for any nonzero r in R. )

The fact that R is its left socle says the homogeneous components generate R, so all that remains is to show the sum is direct. (Hint: if S' is a simple left ideal from a component other than that of T, then S'S=0.)

Comment: @马紫菜 不客气! ${}{}$